# Laravel URL Rerouting

Tags: laravel, routes

I am using this URL in my localhost `192.168.1.5:8000/24hrcares`. So currently if I hit this URL it shows me an error 
`Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException`

So I need to put this in URL  -> `http://192.168.1.5:8000/24hrcares/signin`.

I want that if somebody hits `http://192.168.1.5:8000/24hrcares/` this will automatically go to this URL: `http://192.168.1.5:8000/24hrcares/signin`. And also in place of 24hrcares, there would by any other folder name also.

Do we have any specific rule defined for this? Please help me.

Comment: so when user signed in they can visit 192.168.1.5:8000/24hrcare otherwise it will redirect to 192.168.1.5:8000/24hrcare/signin - is that what you trying to achieve?

Comment: But do you want a *real* redirection, or a routing rewrite?